# Android Kitkat OS for Lenovo Vibe K5 (lollipop) Device?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.1-lollipop, lenovo, compatibility

I have Lenovo vibe K5 device and its running on Lollipop 5.1, for some reasons i want to downgrade it into Kitkat, So is it safe to downgrade higher end device into lower version of android if yes, i need compatible Kitkat OS for this device?

Comment: While _asking us to find what you need us off-topic_, it's generally safe to downgrade, _should you find an appropriate, tested firmware_.

Comment: Unless in _very, very_ rare cases, it's impossible to go below a phone's initial factory firmware version, _even_ with custom ROMs.